# Change value on specific lines of multiple files

Tags: powershell, line

I am testing software which has settings in text files. 
Now i need to change a specific line in ~100 files.

I searched hours for it and i am close to a solution. But dont know how to get it done.

A solution in notepad++ would be nice, but i tried it with powershell with the following command:

```
# File to change
$file = *.dat

# Get file content and store it into $content variable
$content = Get-Content -Path $file

# Replace the line number 40 with "0"
$content[39] = '"0"'

# Set the new content
$content | Set-Content -Path $file
```

It changes the specific line, but it also adds the data of all the files, in all the files in the folder. So in case of 200 lines the files now have 20000 lines. Every file.

I want to change in all the files linenumber 40:

"0"
change to 
"1"

Because there are multiple values with "0" on other lines, i only want to change line 40 in multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to ***iterate*** over these files. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem *.dat | ForEach-Object {
   $content = Get-Content -Path $_ 
   $content[39] = '"0"'
   $content | Set-Content -Path $_
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This works like a charm and saves me alot of time.